# Master mind in console

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to make some sort of mastermind game in the console where the computer generates a 3 digit code and you have to guess it. The computers also tells you which digit you get right after you take a guess. How would i best do this? I don't know a way to "chop up" input so that i can make the computer check it against the digit it has.

example:

computer generates random code: 123

you guess: 321

computer :  -*-  (the star indicates which digit you got right)

I have an idea about how i'd indicate what digits are right or not, but i don't know how to separate the input into parts

Comment: FYI: A `string` can [easily become](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) a `char[]`, or indexed like one

Comment: Hint: `input[0]` gets the first digit as a char.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the computer generated random number into a string. The user input is given as string anyway.
The `string` type has an indexer allowing you to access single characters

```
string s = "abc";
char a = s[0]; 
char b = s[1];
char c = s[2];

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"s[{i}] = '{s[i]}'");
}
```

You write `char` literals as

```
char ch = 'x';
```

using single quotes.

Example:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int code = SomehowGenerateRandomCode();
string codeString = code.ToString();

// Let's assume that both numbers have 3 digits.
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if(userInput[i] == codeString[i]) {
        // digits are equal
    } else {
        // digits are different
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is to work only with characters. Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

To split an `int` to its digits you can convert to string an split like:

```
int i = 123;
string myInt = i.ToString();
List<int>  digits =new List<int>();

foreach (char c in myInt)
{
   digits.Add(int.Parse(c.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This seems inefficient.  Just do `i.ToString()` and you can access the index that way.  We know OP is using a console which takes input as a string or char, using `int` is _much_ more work